# Smoothing texured walls

Tags: drywall

I'm currently in the process of smoothing my textured walls.I covered the walls with several layers of all purpose joint compound. I am now at the sanding part,but I now have ripples on the wall ..how can I get rid of them.

Comment: Ashley, Just a side note incase you didn't know they existed....because you are creating a thicker wall your receptacles/outlets and light switches will need to come out further as well and for this purpose they make outlet spacers.

Answer (score 2):

Plaster. Dry. Sand. Decide if it's flat enough. If not, repeat until it is.

That's just the nature of the beast. It's why getting the job done professionally takes so many hours.

(It's also why the places where I patched and reinforced plaster are just smooth enough that I consider them acceptable

Comment: Almost sounds easier and faster to just slap new drywall over it.

Comment: Or cut out and replace a section, then deal only with having to smooth the edges. In my case, plaster-over-lath, I did a mixture of these... and during other renovations, discovered that the dining room remodel had been done by exactly that add-a-layer approach, resulting in an inch of plaster before reaching the lath.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @keshlam but wanted to add a couple of notes.

There's nothing better (or worse, if you can't handle the truth) than a bright floodlight set to the side of the wall you've recently skimmed. That'll show you where to take it down or build it up.

You didn't specify what tools you were using, but a wide -- like 14" -- knife/trowel is a must for an amateur. (And don't be offended by the term. I've been a carpenter for 20 years and still consider myself an amateur when faced with mud.)

The level of quality you need to strive for should be driven to a certain degree by the nature of the light that hits your surfaces. Sideways light (natural or artificial) is much less flattering.

Flat paint, or as low sheen as you can possibly justify, will be more forgiving than something shiny.

If you've had it with this smooth lark, google "old world drywall finish" for something a little more, um, organic.

If you've really had it, hire a pro.

Comment: Yes, the wider the trowel the better.  What you'll do is when working from one side to the other is slightly  and  I mean **SLIGHTLY** put more pressure on the side that is the "finish side" as you work across the wall.    I don't support the idea of sanding between coats, you can use the trowel to scrap off high spots , ....OK, maybe a tiny bit of sanding to kill the high spots.  I did this on a  rental and it took several passes, Last pass would probably need sanding, light, but use as wide a sanding approach as possible...maybe a 2x4 wrapped in sandpaper, it shouldn't take much.

Comment: Go ahead and **go big, really big** to solve flatness problems. Buy a 4 or 6 foot featheredge tool. It's not quite the difference between the walk to the chemist's and space, but it's a lot bigger than a 14" knife.